# Import MySQL dump file into MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, import, mysql

Browsermob / Neustar produces a MySQLdump file that you can use to query load test data without incurring cloud hours (which are naturally billable). The dump file is a standard dump file, and although I understand that mysqldump has a [compatible=mssql option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible), I am obviously not in a position to run that myself. Looking at the contents of the file (which is extremely large) using a text editor seems to show a series of SQL statements ending in a massive bulk insert. I tried to open the file in Microsoft SQL Management Studio but it crashed (known bug) because the file was too large.

So, does anyone know of a tool that will import the MySQL dump file into MsSQL. The only options I can think of are to install MySQL and import the dump file into that instead and then transfer the data over ODBC, but I really don't want to install MySQL unless I have to.

**IMPORTANT: So, just to be clear, I have a dump file, nothing else and I can't access the database, nor re-run the dump with any options. I have to work with the file I have been given.**

Any ideas?

First lines of the file look like this:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.58, for debian-linux-gnu (i686)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: collector
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.1.58-1ubuntu1

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `name_value_pairs`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `name_value_pairs`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `name_value_pairs` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `tx_id` char(24) NOT NULL,
  `step_id` int(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `name_value_pairs_id` (`id`),
  KEY `name_value_pairs_tx_id` (`tx_id`),
  KEY `name_value_pairs_step_id` (`step_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `name_value_pairs`
--

LOCK TABLES `name_value_pairs` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `name_value_pairs` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `name_value_pairs` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `object`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `object`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `object` (
  `bytes` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `domain` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `end_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `err_msg` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `host` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `method` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `obj_id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `obj_num` mediumint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(4096) NOT NULL,
  `partial_url_md5` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `protocol` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `resolved_ip_addr` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `status_code` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `step_id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time_active` mediumint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `blocked_time` mediumint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `dns_lookup_time` mediumint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `connect_time` mediumint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ssl_handshake_time` mediumint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `send_time` mediumint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_to_first_byte` mediumint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `receive_time` mediumint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `tx_id` char(24) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(4096) NOT NULL,
  KEY `object_partial_url_md5` (`partial_url_md5`),
  KEY `object_obj_id` (`obj_id`),
  KEY `object_obj_num` (`obj_num`),
  KEY `object_step_id` (`step_id`),
  KEY `object_tx_id` (`tx_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `object`
--

LOCK TABLES `object` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `object` DISABLE KEYS */;
```

Then comes the bulk insert.

Comment: you can use mysql.exe to import it, mysql -u username -p -h host databasename < yourdumpfile.sql

Comment: @DorinDuminica I don't have MySQL installed, and I'm trying to avoid installing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information in the file is only to delete and recreate the schema of the database (that I assume you already have), so you probably don't need that.

The bulk insert part is the interesting, probably you can isolate that part for each table to different files and upload it to MsSQL with BULK INSERT from T-SQL, you are able to define delimiter and other settings for this BULK insert you it should fit whatever format you have..

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, I need to parse this file and convert the SQL statements to something that MsSQL can understand?

Comment: Yes, assuming you already have the schema created, remove all create/alter table from the file. Then just check if the inserts are not compatible with MsSQL and try to adjust them (shouldn't be many changes) to MsSQL format. And run it.

Comment: As far as I can see, manually editing the file is my only option for the moment. I'm going to leave this question open for a bit to see if anyone else comes up with a more automated way to transform these files, but if not the answer will go to you.

Answer (score -2):

That's official docs MS docs.

Migrating MySQL to Microsoft SQL Server 2000
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966396.aspx

Comment: Please re-read the question. I don't have access to the database, only the dump file (as is).