# Import MySQL DBDUMP DB to MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I have a DB dump of a MySQL DB. Now i need to add all those  tables and data to MSSQL using the MySQL DBDUMP (Import MySQL DB to MSSQL).

I have read a few [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228876/import-mysql-dump-file-into-mssql) and [articles](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29106/Migrate-MySQL-to-Microsoft-SQL-Server), but none helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would tend to follow this flow:

- Restore to mysql (easy)
- Use a data pump of some kind to pull from mysql to sql server
  (there are many tools, here is one http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/mssql/datapump )

These steps will be quick and reliable and no headache....

Comment: I have downloaded the trial version of it, But how do i use it to populate MSSQL from MySQL ? What are the steps of doing so

Comment: @Illep data pump tools are usually pretty straightforward. I don't know that tool cold, so can't talk you through it step by step, but I am sure their docs/wizard will make it happen.