# How to import MySQL 4 .dump file into MySQL 5?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

I have a MySQL 4 dump file named `booster.dump` that is 30MB in size. I want to import this file to a MySQL 5 server. I try it by using phpMyAdmin. But it doesn't upload. It shows an error:

> size is very large

Then I have zip this file named `booster.zip` and try to upload again in phpMyAdmin then it show an error:

> No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration

Then I open the `booster.dump` file in Notepad++ and copy all text and make a new file named `booster.sql` then I try to upload `booster.sql` in phpMyAdmin. Then it shows an error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 8

I have change `TYPE=MyISAM` To `ENGINE=MyISAM` and it works fine. Now if I go with this way then I need to change every query which very much painful.

My question is: is there any way to import this file into MySQL 5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import MySQL dump file into MSSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228876/import-mysql-dump-file-into-mssql)

Answer (score 2):

***MySQL 4 to 5***

```
1. Export the database on the system with MySQL 4:

mysqldump -p --opt dbname >dbname.sql
```

---

```
2. Copy the database to the other sytem, for example,

scp dbname.sql me@domain.com:/home/me
```

---

```
3. To import the database on the system with MySQL 5:

mysqladmin -p drop dbname

mysqladmin -p create dbname

mysql -p -D dbname <dbname.sql
```

---

**Update: 1**

**1.From the command prompt go to the root of the server**

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin>
```

**2.Load the dumb file into the server using following command**

```
bin>mysql -uroot -p<server_password> {database_name} < {complete filepath}

Example:bin>MySQL -uroot -ppassword mydb < C:\Users\Anto\Documents\DB_Dumb
```

Comment: sorry for late replay. I have no mysql4 sarver. I got `booster.dump` file from another person.

Answer (score 1):

The .dump extension is nonstandard and may be interfering with the process here; if it's really just an SQL file I would suggest changing the extension to .sql. Some of the phpMyAdmin import functionality works off of the extension.

Anyway, have you seen the "SQL compatibility mode" dropdown when on the phpMyAdmin import screen? From there you can select MYSQL40 or MYSQL323 in an effort to get the file to import. See the screenshot below.

As an aside, I'm having no problems with MySQL 5.1.73 importing files with both TYPE= and ENGINE= statements. What exact MySQL and phpMyAdmin versions do you have?

[image: phpMyAdmin's MySQL compatibility dropdown]